# What is the first parameter of class methods in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class-method

According to my understanding, the first argument passed in a class method is the class itself where that class method is defined. So for example, consider the following code:

```
class A(object):
    __x=10

    @classmethod
    def clam(cls,*args):
        print(cls.__x)

class B(A):
    __x=50
```

And when i called :

```
B.clam()
```

the output was **10** which is OK as per my understanding because the class method being called is defined in **class A**, so **class A** will be passed implicitly to **clam()** and the value of **__x** there is **10**.

But when i ran the following code:

```
class A(object):
    x=10

    @classmethod
    def clam(cls,*args):
        print(cls.x)

class B(A):
    x=50
```

and when i called:

```
 B.clam()
```

My life was suddenly ruined. The output is **50**.

**The only difference between both the cases is that x was private in former one.**

What happened exactly? Why the output from the later one is 50 ? Was there any scope change or suddenly the first parameter passed to class method defined in **A** became **class B** ?

Comment: In the first snippet you invoked *"name mangling"*, and `_A__x` is different from `_B__x`. **`cls` is the class you invoke the method on, not the class you define it on**; the second behaviour is exactly what you *should* have expected. And note that downvoters aren't required to comment, whether or not they know the answer.

Comment: double underscore invoke Python's name mangling mechanics. And since the function is defined inside class `A` the line `print(cls.__x)` is internally converted to something like `print(cls._A__x)`. This does not happen in the second case (the first parameter is always the class on which the function is called, so it would be `B` in both calls)

Comment: The `cls` parameter is the class on which you are calling the method, *not* the class that defines the method. You only got `10` in the first test because name mangling distinguishes the fields in the two classes. That's part of the reason name mangling exists - to prevent you shadowing private fields.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i did not know the answer, So i asked it. I was not able to understand the reason behind that negative.

Comment: I understand that, but that doesn't mean you should: 1. hassle people who downvote for explanations; or 2. assume that they downvote because they don't know the answer.

Comment: But because of the downvote, i may not get the answer of my query because by looking at the downvote, a person like me trust that the question was not at all eligible to be at stackoverflow.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242816/what-is-the-first-parameter-of-class-methods-in-python#comment67747916_40242816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in the class method is the class on which you are calling the method, not (necessarily) the class that defines the method. (Having a variable that always holds the same class would probably not be that useful.)

In the first case, name mangling distinguishes the two fields, to protect you from accidentally shadowing private variables in a subclass. The field `A.__x` becomes `A._A__x` and `B.__x` becomes `B._B__x`. This ensures that you can't accidentally pick up a field in a subclass with a similar name to your private field in `A`. That's part of the reason name mangling exists.

In the second case, there is no name mangling: you get the `x` field as defined in `B`, the class you are calling the method on.

Comment: But i am still not able to understand that when B.clam() called and class B was passed as first parameter, how it ensures that __x present in the method will resolve to A.A__x and not B.B__x ?

Comment: @Shasha99 because the name mangling *is* invoked on the basis of the class in which the method is defined, **not** based on the `cls` argument.

Comment: So you are saying that both A__x and B__x will come in the scope of class B ?

Comment: @Shasha99 you could test that yourself - implement the following as a class method in `B`: `def clam(cls,*args): print(cls.__x); super(B, cls).clam(*args)`. Then call `B.clam()` again.

Comment: I tried that. Thanks for help. But i am still not able to sort out the relation between class B and A__x becuase class B is now being passed in class method of A, then how are we getting reference to A__x using class B ?

Comment: I thought that i am an intermediate guy in python. Things are changed now :)

Comment: @Shasha99 `B` inherits the field `_A__x` from `A`. So `B` has both `_A__x` and `_B__x`.

Comment: Got it and tested it as well. Thanks for your kind help.